# Converting Timestamp to Beginning of Next Business Day

Tags: python, timestamp

first question so far on stack overflow, so apologies if I miss any of the conventions. I have been trying unsuccessfully to convert any timestamp that is outside of business hours to the beginning of the next business day. Anyone have any suggestions on how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code and we're happy to help you.

Comment: Do you need the algorithm to take national holidays into account?

Comment: Well, I initially started by converted the date to a timestamp: df_ticket['Open'] = pd.to_datetime(df_ticket.Open)    

After that I created variables to indicate  day of week:

df_ticket['O_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df_ticket['Open']).dt.weekday_name

And one to break a day down into 24 hours, code 0 if before 9 am, 1 during business day, 2 if after:

df_ticket['TOD_open'] = df_ticket['TOD_open'].apply({0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:1, 10:1, 11:1, 12:1, 13:1, 14:1, 15:1, 16:1, 15:1, 16:1, 17:2, 18:2, 19:2, 20:2, 21:2, 22:2, 23:2 }.get)

Comment: I planned to use a series of if statements to move the date to 9 am the same day if before 9 am on a business day, and to 9 am the next business day if after 5 pm, and automatically to 9 am Monday if on a Saturday or Sunday. But this seemed a little too complex.

Comment: And Stefan, national holiday are not crucial

Comment: BTW, both of you thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that depends on a programming language or do You want a bare algorithm for that?
In PHP we have something like this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2018-11-01 +1 Weekday'));
```

and strtotime (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can provide You with various calculations.

Comment: Thanks for responding Ignas. I am coding in Python.